# Checkbox trigger multiple select with React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm building a React application for my clients. Each Client, when log-in, can access different views for each his location office. So first I list all the office of the client, and for each its office, he cans select the views he wants to display.

**My Problem :**

Let say I have office 1 that can choose to access to view 1 and view 2 and office 2 that can access to the same views. When I click on view 1 for office 1, it triggers view 2 for office 2 also !

[image: I click on view 1 for office 1, it selects view 1 for office 2 also]

Here is the code :

```
<div >
        {
          //I take all the offices of a client
          officesArray.map((office, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h3>site {(office.name)}</h3>
                <div key={index}>
                  //For each office I display the views available to select
                  viewsArray.map((view, index) => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <label
                          for={`${view.name}${office.name}`}
                        >
                          <input
                            key={`${index}${office.id}`}
                            type="checkbox"
                            id={`${view.name}${office.name}`}
                            name={`${view.name}${office.name}`}
                            value={`${view.name}${office.name}`}
                            checked={checkedState[index]}
                            onChange={() => handleOnChange(index, office.id)}
                          />
                          {view.name}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
```

And here is the handleonchange function  :

```
const handleOnChange = (position, office) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );
    prop.set({ id: (prop.views)[position].id_view, officeId: office })
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
  }
```

Comment: Show `handleOnChange`

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: You have one and the same `checkedState` array for every office. You need separate once. Nested array for example.

Comment: Thanks. But here is the state `const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array((numberOffices * nbreViews)).fill(false)
  );` So I should create as many state as offices. Is it possible ?

Comment: If it is declared that way it means you are only using part of this array and the rest is always false.

Comment: exactly. I'm only using the two first parts, the two other are always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state like this:

```
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(new Array(numberOffices).fill().map(() => new Array(nbreViews).fill(false)));
```

Update the state like this:

```
const handleOnChange = (position, office) => {
  const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((off, id) => off.map((item, index) =>
    (id === office && index === position) ? !item : item
  ));
  // ...
  setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's better ! Now it send back a good selection. But handleOnChange doesn't update the checkedState, and juste the last checkbox of each office can be check, the others are checked by defaut and can't be unchecked

Comment: Sorry I missed to update the handleChange call, so that works perfectly. You saved me hours of work. Thank you a lot !